# Netbeans: Tab spaces in Grails GSP

Tags: grails, netbeans, gsp

When using the netbeans grails plugin most source files follow the IDEs tab rules in the options (e.g. Java and Groovy files are 4 spaces) but when editing a Grails GSP (essentially HTML) the tabs default to 2 spaces and not the 4 spaces set in the options. This is becoming slightly annoying since I have to backtrack and retab some areas of the source because netbeans insists on making it 2 spaces indentation when completing a block.

Is there a way to force the tabs to 4 spaces for GSP files in netbeans?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using nb 6.9+ i believe there is a project code formatting tool (right click on the project and go to properties and then formatting).  But I don't think this will help you since there is a bug with formatting GSP in netbeans....[(see)](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=168004).  **Just don't auto format your code using the IDE for now (that's what i'm forced to do).**

Comment: Thanks, although it does not solve my problem I will upvote your answer. Would have been nice to fix such a bug in their later release such as Netbeans 7 which is what I am using. I generally don't use auto reformat menu function but when you close a gsp tag or html tag it automatically reformats that particular block regardless, well at least on my installation.

Comment: I hear ya and thank you.  It's a pain especially if you like me who races through code and then just hits the hot keys for formatting.  Hard habit to break.  I've switched to Spring STS (eclipse) for my grails development and they seem to have the same issues over there.